# Using if statements within a loop creates an invalid parameter error

Tags: vba, excel

I've written the below code in Excel to create an XY scatter chart and format the points to create a visual timeline of events/decisions made within a specified period (between `sDate` and `eDate`).

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateTimeline()

'Updates timeline chart with dates in specified range and updates formatting

    Dim timelineChart As Chart
    Dim recordCount As Long
    Dim record As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    timelineSheet.Unprotect
    Call ClearSeries
    Set timelineChart = Worksheets("Timeline").ChartObjects("chtDecisionTimeline").Chart
    recordCount = 0
    For Each record In Range(decisionRecordSheet.Range("D7"), decisionRecordSheet.Range("D7").End(xlDown))
        recordCount = recordCount + 1
        If record.Value >= timelineSheet.Range("sDate") Then
            If record.Value <= timelineSheet.Range("eDate") Then
                timelineChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                With timelineChart.SeriesCollection(recordCount)
                    .Name = "='Decision Record'!" & record.Offset(0, 1).Address
                    .XValues = "='Decision Record'!" & record.Address
                    .Values = "='Decision Record'!" & record.Offset(0, -2).Address
                    .AxisGroup = 2
                    .MarkerStyle = 8
                    .MarkerSize = 7
                    .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(228, 10, 56)
                    .MarkerForegroundColor = -2
                    .Format.Line.Visible = False
                    .ApplyDataLabels
                    .DataLabels.ShowValue = False
                    .DataLabels.ShowSeriesName = True
                    .DataLabels.Orientation = xlUpward
                        If record.Offset(0, -2).Value Mod 2 <> 0 Then
                            timelineChart.SeriesCollection(recordCount).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionRight
                        Else
                            timelineChart.SeriesCollection(recordCount).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionLeft
                        End If
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next
    timelineChart.SetElement (msoElementSecondaryValueAxisNone)
    With timelineChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        .MaximumScale = timelineSheet.Range("eDate").Value
        .MinimumScale = timelineSheet.Range("sDate").Value
    End With
    With timelineChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .MaximumScale = lookupSheet.Range("yMax").Value
        .MinimumScale = lookupSheet.Range("yMin").Value
    End With
    With timelineSheet
        .Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The decisionRecordSheet contains data in the following format in columns B-F:

[image: Image showing layout of decisionRecordSheet data]

And the timelineSheet is set out as follows:

[image]

The code works fine (although I know it's not pretty) except when the date range specified by the user (in `sDate` and `eDate`) means that only 0-2 records need to be plotted on the graph, in which case it throws up an invalid parameter error for `With timelineChart.SeriesCollection(recordCount)`.

I've tried commenting out the line 18,19,42 and 43 and it does appear to the if statements reducing the number of records that meet the criteria that is causing the problem. I have also tried reducing the total dataset so that there are only 0-2 and I get the same error.

Of course this may be nothing to do with the number of records that are being plotted but these are the only tests that have consistently replicated this behaviour.

**EDIT:**

I also get a run time error when there are more than 2 items to plot but only if I have include lines 18,19,42 and 43 in my code - if I comment them out, I no longer get the error.

[image: Error message]

When I debug it appears that the issue is with `timelineChart.SetElement (msoElementSecondaryValueAxisNone)` but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate it as you call out to code we don't have here but: -

If you move `recordCount = recordCount + 1` to come after `timelineChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries`, or change

or

Change `timelineChart.SeriesCollection(recordCount)` to `timelineChart.SeriesCollection(timelineChart.SeriesCollection.Count)`

This may provide a positive result. Your `recordCount` that was being used to find the collection was incremented every time but there is an `if` statement that meant a series may not be made every time.